# Logout Facebook Android SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I use the `LoginButton` from the Facebook Android SDK to login to my application. How do I programmatically log out the user from any Activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically log out from Facebook SDK 3.0 without using Facebook login/logout button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328148/how-to-programmatically-log-out-from-facebook-sdk-3-0-without-using-facebook-log)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you use `closeAndClearTokenInformation()` as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/ ?

See also [How to programmatically log out from Facebook SDK 3.0 without using Facebook login/logout button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328148/how-to-programmatically-logout-from-facebook-sdk-3-0-without-using-facebook-logi)

Comment: Thanks Flaxfield! Can you help with the other problem too, if you know something? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149499/cant-relogin-with-facebook-credentials-after-logout

Answer (score 18):

Starting Facebook SDK 4.0 you need to call

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Comment: I am not seeing that this forces the user to re-authenticate. :(

Comment: Always check access token for null before this logout using logingManager.getInstance.logout();

Answer (score 4):

If you are using facebook SDK 4, you first need to initialize sdk:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

And then just do:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using facebook SDK 4, you first need to initialize sdk:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

And then :

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

 AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
```