# How to programmatically logout from facebook SDK 4.7 without using facebook logout button?

Tags: android

How to programmatically logout from facebook SDK 4.7 without using facebook logout button ? The previous asked question is for sdk 3.0 and i am asking for sdk 4.7. I am new to using facebook login in my android project.

Comment: Duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328148/how-to-programmatically-log-out-from-facebook-sdk-3-0-without-using-facebook-log?rq=1)...already answer given for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the following code whenever you want to logout programmatically.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```