# android: How to get the context of other app in my activity?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to show facebook login context in my app.

I already know about calling facebook app with facebook SDK but is there any way to get only its context in my app?

Like this:
[image]

This is request of our UI designer.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look at this thread maybe this help you:

[How to programmatically log out from Facebook SDK 3.0 without using Facebook login/logout button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328148/how-to-programmatically-log-out-from-facebook-sdk-3-0-without-using-facebook-log)

or this :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK ,  The title of link says it all. tanks anyway.

Comment: consider it as suggestion, because when this answer reached in reviews section then it will marked as **link only answer**. if possible then improve it.

Comment: As I mentioned, I already know how to use facebook SDK. But in general, this calls facebook app externally, right? I want to show only the context of facebook app inside my app and I'm asking the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Facebook SDK to login to Facebook in your app, you can create Facebook Developer account and use Facebook SDK tools.
for more information use the following link :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/
maybe this help you...

Comment: Well, as you see the image above, what I expect is that showing facebook login context inside my activity context 'keeping toolbar of my app'.

Comment: you can create Facebook developer key for your app in Facebook developer account  and use Facebook SDK to receive login token, by this way you can create custom layout and handle  login in your application. for more info i recommend you to read Facebook developer document.